# Virtualbox throwing errors on Windows 10 TP on vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

The VM I was trying to run was running perfectly on a Windows 7 machine.
I had upgraded to Windows 10 and tried out the same machine (with all the same configs and vagrant boxes), uninstalled and reinstalled virtualbox several times, but it still doesn't work.

Tried making a brand new VM - that didn't work too.

[Here's the error](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1046598/8178967/a18edbb4-1430-11e5-9fde-f194c241f53d.JPG)

Some people who had similar 'hostonly' errors have suggested to restart the VirtualBox service from terminal, but I don't know the Windows equivalent of that command.

Anybody had this error before? How do I solve this?

Comment: Try going to control panel -> Services and restart the service there using the GUI.

Comment: Hey @Dan, thanks for the quick reply. But which service? I don't see anything named VIrtualBox in the services section. There is a service named Virtual Disk. Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test build is available at https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.0.1-101902-Win.exe . This should fix the host-only interface creation problem by introducing a 5-second timeout when querying the registry key. We would appreciate feedback (i.e. does it fix the host-only interface creation errors or not, is the timeout long enough).
https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.0.1-101902-Win.exe

See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040#trac-change-55

Uninstalling the current VirtualBox and installing the testbuild worked for me

Comment: Okay, now its not showing the error anymore! :)
But, on the flipside it seems to have stuck at `Clearing any previously set network interfaces` . I think the screen's not refreshing properly, because when I press Ctrl+C, it seems to proceed properly for the next couple of steps.... before canceling the action.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed there was popup box that said "Cannot rename this connection. A connection with the name you specified already exists. Specify a different name".

Dunno what to do next from here....

Comment: How does your vagrantfile look? Did it list your Available network interfaces?

Comment: Nevermind. It worked! Apparently I had to press "OK" on that dialog box to proceed with the installation while keeping the command prompt open. This is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: 5.0.1 r101957 still does not fix the problem. in my Vagrantfile I have config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.102" (ubuntu box guest, windows 10 host) everytime I try to do a vagrant up, it creates a new Ethernet adapter with an incremented #number and an error message pops up saying "Cannot rename connection. A connection with the name you specified already exists. Please specify a different name." And then the box does not boot up. What should be done?

Comment: FIX: The trick is that specifying name of the virtual network adapter in the Vagrantfile such as config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.102" name: "Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" - will skip creating of virtual adapters as well as the error

Comment: Yea, I also had this problem, I solved it the same way as saraf, by adding the name of the interface it should use.

Comment: I have the same problem as @saraf with the same version, but I use boot2docker which doesn't have the option to specify the virtual network adapter name

Comment: crramirez: try setting Compatibility mode to Windows 8 or 7 for all executables in the VirtualBox folder (perhaps VBoxHeadless.exe or VirtualBox.exe would do ... but just to be safe) (I assume you are using Windows 10) then the option to specify the network adapter name might not be necessary. That is how I fixed it finally.

Comment: @saraf: +1 Thanks! That's another good info. For me clicking "OK" on the popup box I mentioned above did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and it seems to be a problem with changed network security in Windows and still no updated for it in Virtualbox.

Comment: Oh. Is it? Do let me know if you can find a solution. I tried posting an issue on the puphpet's github as well as vagrant's github pages. No solution yet.

Comment: Yeah, I am keeping track of it.. If something comes up I will post back.

Comment: Check the answer to my laracasts question, I didn't try yet, maybe it works.. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead

Comment: Hey, I tried it out, its the same as the other answer posted above.. but no luck still the same error.

Comment: The problem I think is the command "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs" doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but a working solution (tested under Win10 build10130). This is what I did to get homestead up and working

1. Uninstall Vagrant and VirtualBox (restart if necessary)
2. Install notepad+ or other notepad replacement that handles linux line-endings
3. Download Vagrant v1.7.2, VirtualBox 5.0RC1, VirtualBox v4.3.6
4. Enable built-in administrator account.
   net user administrator /active:yes
5. switch to Administrator account
6. Install Vagrant v1.7.2 (restart if necessary, log back into Administrator)
7. Install VirtualBox v5.0RC1
8. Install VirtualBox v4.3.6
9. Update VBox Host-Only adaptor driver (device manager,Search Automatically)
10. Edit VagrantFile file (where ever you vagrant up from) and change all ~/ to C:/Users/username/
11. Edit Homestead.yaml (Where ever you had it, likely C:\Users\username\.homestead) and change all ~/ to C:/Users/username/
12. Open VirtualBox
13. Run vagrant up
14. switch back to your usual user (do not sign out of Adminstrator)

hey presto, you have a working homestead

Each time after to manage vagrant (start, halt, whatever) switch to Administrator, manage, and switch back to your usual user. Do not sign out of the Administrator account when switching if you have a box up

Comment: :) Thanks for answering this question. I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: It did @maxxon15 on build 10130 however not since build 10158/10159

Comment: Hmm. Probably something wrong with my Win10 installation then. I have been facing error with Windows updates for quite some time now.